# How to load Kaggle datasets into Intel DevCloud Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, intel, kaggle

I'm a new user of Intel DevCloud and trying to load dataset directly from kaggle. How can I do that. I tried the following approach.

```
pip install kaggle
kaggle competitions download -c bengaliai-cv19
```

But Kaggle is not being installed. It says:

```
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/glob/intel-python/versions/2018u2/intelpython3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/text_unidecode'
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Open a terminal in dev cloud (+ on top left corner)
2. Type following in the terminal

   `pip install kaggle`
3. To use Kaggle API, create an account in kaggle official page(https://www.kaggle.com). Then, go to "**My Account**" tab of user's profile and select "**create new API token**". This will download the kaggle.json file in your system.
4. Upload .json file to devcloud
5. type the command to copy .json file to the kaggle root folder

   `cp -r "kaggle.json" "/home/u51xxx/.kaggle"`
6. To check the list of datasets available

   `kaggle datasets list -s bengaliai-cv19`

[image]

(-s refers search, followed by the name of the dataset)

7. To download the dataset type:

   `kaggle datasets download (filename obtained in the list)`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try out the below steps to access Kaggle API in devcloud through command line.

**Step 1:** create a conda enviroment and then Install kaggle using pip as follows

```
conda create -n my_env -c intel python=3.6

source activate my_env

pip install kaggle --user
```

Now, run

```
kaggle -h
```

to check whether it is installed successfully.

**Step 2:** To use Kaggle API, create an account in kaggle official page(https://www.kaggle.com). Then, go to "My Account" tab of user's profile and select "create new API token". This will download the kaggle.json file in your system.

**Step 3:** Create a .kaggle folder in devcloud home folder

```
mkdir .kaggle
```

Now, copy the kaggle.json to that folder.

**Step 4:** In order to download kaggle datasets,first search for your desired dataset using the below command in devcloud terminal

```
kaggle datasets list -s [KEYWORD]
```

Eg: If you want to download creditcard fraud detection dataset, then search like this

```
kaggle datasets list -s credit
```

It will list all the datasets available with this keyword.
For example,

```
    isaikumar/creditcardfraud                            Credit Card Fraud Detection Dataset                  66MB  2018-05-05 09:38:01           1797         30  0.5882353
    ananta/credit-card-data                              Credit Card Data                                      1MB  2018-08-24 02:22:36           1218         15  0.64705884
    wendykan/lending-club-loan-data                      Lending Club Loan Data                              720MB  2019-03-18 18:43:12          68843       1238  0.7352941
```

**Step 5:** To download the dataset titled "Credit Card Fraud Detection Dataset",

```
kaggle datasets download isaikumar/creditcardfraud
```

Hope it helps.